# Images alignment from database into html page

Tags: javascript, php, html, eclipse

i currently have a code that can append the result into the html page.

This is the append code.

```
function casefeed(response) {
    var arr = JSON.parse(response);
    var i;

    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

    $("#viewcase").append("<td><img src='" + serverURL() 
            + "/images/"+ arr[i].Case_Pic + "' height='100'>"
            + "<td>" + arr[i].CaseTime + "</a></b></td>");

   }

   }
```

This is my table format.

```
 <table class="tile-table">
     <tbody id = "viewcase">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="tile" style="background-position: -0px -0px;"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="tile" style="background-position: px -0px;"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="tile" style="background-position: -200px -0px;"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="tile" style="background-position: -300px -0px;"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

My current result is like this.
[image]

Is it possible to display the image into this format?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding nth-child(n). for sample i m considering the array as numbers from 1 to 9 . you can pass your url in the place of imageurl

```js
$(function() {
  function casefeed() {
    var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
    var i;

    var imageurl = "http://feelgrafix.com/data/images/images-1.jpg";
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (i % 3 == 0) {
        $("#viewcase").append("<tr></tr>");
      }

      $("#viewcase:nth-child(n)").append("<td><img src='" + imageurl + "' >Time</td>");

    }

  }
  casefeed();
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
}
td {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tile-table">
  <tbody id="viewcase">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are appending `td` to `tbody`, you should append it to `tr`. Also, there are two closing tags without opening tags - `</a></b>`

This is what I suggest:

HTML

```
<table class="tile-table">
  <tbody id = "viewcase"> 
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript

```
function casefeed(response) {
    var arr = JSON.parse(response);
    var i;

    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (i % 3 === 0)
        $("#viewcase").append("tr"); // add new table row each 3 elements

      $("#viewcase tr").last().append("<td><img src='" + serverURL() 
            + "/images/"+ arr[i].Case_Pic + "' height='100'>"
            + "<td><p>" + arr[i].CaseTime + "</p></td>");
     }

   }
```